# Apps Scripts Google Sheets - Move Row based on Cell value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am not a coder, and trying to manipulate some code (pre-existing/ some added from a partner) but still struggling on small section/ issue.

**script (original) written to getRow with active**

```
  // Get the number of the row to move
  var rowToMove = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  Logger.log("rowToMove: " + rowToMove);
```

trying change to have it getRow based on cell value. Have gotten it to where it searches defined range. But trying to get it to, based on the value, preform the getRow as it did in the code above... not successful.

any suggestions welcome, happy to provide more info as well.
[image: screenshot of spreadsheet]

```js
function moveRows(){
    Logger.log("moveRows.gs > moveRows");

    // Confirmation check
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.alert("Move Row", "Confirm Completed Tasks", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (response == ui.Button.YES) {

        // Start: Get the data to move

            // Get the current sheet object
            var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
            
            // Get the number of columns
            var lastColumnOfDataInActiveSheet = activeSheet.getLastColumn();
            Logger.log("lastColumnOfDataInActiveSheet: " + lastColumnOfDataInActiveSheet);
    
            **// Get the number of the row to move
            var rowToMove = activeSheet.getRange('E2:E500').getValues();
            rowToMove.forEach( function (r, i) {
              Logger.log(r);
              if (r[0]) 
                activeSheet.getRow();
            }); 
            // Get the range to move
            var rangeToCopyFrom = activeSheet.getRange(rowToMove, 1, 1, lastColumnOfDataInActiveSheet);**

        // End: Get the data to move

        // Start: Copy and paste the data
        
            // Get the target sheet
            var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Completed");
            
            // Get last row in target sheet
            var lastRowInTargetSheet = targetSheet.getLastRow();
            Logger.log("lastRowInTargetSheet: " + lastRowInTargetSheet);
            
            // Get range to paste to
            var rangeToPasteTo = targetSheet.getRange(lastRowInTargetSheet + 1, 1, 1, lastColumnOfDataInActiveSheet);
            
            // Copy and paste the data
            rangeToCopyFrom.copyTo(rangeToPasteTo, {contentsFormat:true});
        
        // End: Copy and paste the data

        // Clear the source data
        rangeToCopyFrom.clearContent();

        // Sort the source sheet
        var lastRowOfDataInActiveSheet = activeSheet.getLastRow();
        var rangeToSort = activeSheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRowOfDataInActiveSheet - 1, lastColumnOfDataInActiveSheet);
        rangeToSort.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});

        // Pop up box tells you it's done
        
    }; // End: Confirmation check

}; // End: moveRows
```

Comment: There is no method Sheet.getRow().

Comment: rowToMove is actuall a 2d array of values in the activesheet

Answer (score 0):

#### Address my two commented lines and maybe you can get it to work

```
function moveRows(){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.alert("Move Row", "Confirm Completed Tasks", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
            var ash = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
            var avs = ash.getRange('E2:E500').getValues();
            avs.forEach( function (r, i) {
              if (r[0]) 
                ash.getRow();//there is no sheet.getRow();
            }); 
            var srg = ash.getRange(avs, 1, 1, ash.getLastColumn());//avs is a two dimensional array of data not a number
            var tsh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Completed");
            var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1,1);
            srg.copyTo(trg, {contentsFormat:true});
        srg.clearContent();
        var rangeToSort = ash.getRange(2, 1, ash.getLastRow() - 1, ash.getLastColumn());
        rangeToSort.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
    }; 
};
```